# How do I override ToString() for a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dictionary, tostring

I have a `Dictionary<string, FieldDefinition>` dependency property that when I bind it to a WPF list box I want it to just print the string (not the FieldDefinition).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, here, but I think you are looking for the `Keys` property on the dictionary; this will return a collection of `TKey` values (in your case, the 'string' part of your dictionary, not the FieldDefinition part, which incidentally would be available via the `Values` Property)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary.Keys}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

I would create a class that either implements IDictionary

```
public class CustomDictionary : IDictionary
{
...
}
```

or inherits Dictionary

```
public class CustomDictionary : Dictionary<string, FieldDefinition>
{
...
}
```

and override the `ToString` method in this class like this:

```
public override string ToString() 
  {
     return "My custom string";
  }
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to override ToString, but not quite what the OP is asking. IanR is on the right track there.

Comment: well, it was what the *title* of the question was, but not the actual thing the OP was trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 2):

Derive a class from Dictionary, override ToString().